# Partitioning the remainder of the hard drive shows substantially less space than should be available

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Dell XPS13 with 1TB of memory and Ubuntu loaded on it.  The current Ubuntu installation has three partitions associated with it.  I would like to wipe the hard drive and install Arch linux with LVM and encryption, which requires the creation of three partitions.  I am using the `disk /dev/sdc` command to create the partitions.  When I used the command, I was presented with a warning stating `GPT PBMR size mismatch (1503895 != 60628991) will be corrected by write`.  Despite the warning I continued with the process of providing the inputs to create two 500 MB partitions, which was completed successfully.  However, at the third prompt for `Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size(K,M,G,T,P} (2050048-60628958, default 60628958):` I just hit enter without providing a number, which should allocate all remaining space to the third partition; however, I received the following message `Created a new partition 3 of type 'Linux filesystem' and size 27.9 GiB`, which is obviously much less than the remaining space which should be 1 TB minus 1 GB.  At this point the commands are only in memory and have not been written.  Is the estimation of 27.9 GiB in error because of the GPT size mismatch, and will this be fixed when written to disk if I go that far, or is there something wrong with the partitioning that should force me to abandon the install?

Comment: Are we mixing up GiB and GB? For instance, 1 TB is only 931 GiB. See [Wikipedia - Multiple-byte units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units)

Comment: Nope, the message states that it is allocating the remaining 27.9 GiB, when in reality there should be far much more left over after allocating two +500M partitions.

Comment: Did you delete the existing partitions before attempting this?

Comment: No, I just solved the issue this morning and as usual is was something simple.  I will update my question to show it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The computer had a hard drive pre-installed to support future windows applicability.  I accidentally tried to format wrong hard drive i.e. `/dev/sdc` when I should have been trying to format the `/dev/nvme0n1` hard drive.  I ran the correct commands today and was able to correctly partition the hard drive and install Arch Linux to a bootable state.